# how to open new console window using Ansi C?

Tags: c, winapi, console

i am beginner in Anci c programming here is the description for my program
 my program first asks user to press any key then  a new console is opened and the user inputs any number he want then the console is closed and the number he typed is printed in the parent console ,i hope this clear and thanks for reply

so i want the function that opens a new console
i am using Code::Blocks gcc compiler under win 7

Comment: ANSI C does not have the concept multiple consoles (e.g. like multiple windows). Please specify your platform.

Comment: thanks for replay 
i am using windows

Comment: you need to edit your question and remove all references to ANSI C as 'ANSI C' and 'console' are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

"ANSI C" doesn't know there is such a thing as "consoles" or "windows".  This is almost certainly going to depend on the operating system and/or windowing environment being used, as well as any third-party libraries being used to drive these kinds of operations.  Maybe something like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) would be helpful here, but there's no way of knowing without more specific information.

Comment: sorry Lack of clarity for my question 
the program first ask user to press any key then
then a new console is opened and the user inputs any number he want 
then the console is closed and the number he typed is printed in the  parent console ,i hope this clear
and thanks for reply

Comment: @mohammed sameeh - you should edit your question to contain the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI C doesn't have a concept of "windows".  That's an operating system concept outside the area of the C language.

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned, this doesn't make sense for ANSI C.  For Windows, you'll need to be more specific about what you want.

If you're writing a console application (done automatically if you're using `main`, or if you explicitly pass the [`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28VS.80%29.aspx) flag to the linker), you don't need to do anything special.  Running your application from a windowed application will spawn a console window for you.  Running it from an existing console window will reuse that one.

If you're writing a windowed application (done automatically if you're using `WinMain`, or if you explicitly pass the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` flag to the linker), you can use [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx).  See the [Creation of a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682528%28VS.85%29.aspx) article from MSDN. (I think you also should be able to do that if you're writing a console application and never want to reuse an existing console, but I'd have to say that doing so would be very user-unfriendly.)

Answer (score 0):

```
system("cmd");
```

should do the trick

Comment: This assumes Windows. system("xterm"); is a safe bet under Linux.

Comment: Erm, in what universe is that going to "do the trick"?  And I'm not sure that counts as "ANSI C".

Comment: can you tell the header file please